# A doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I wrote a program to manage Bank accounts by the means of a doubly linked list, but I found a problem with the cancellation procedure.

```
void suppCompte (int numCpt) {
    CompteBancaire *pnt = first;
    if (first==NULL) {
        printf("la liste vide !\n");
    }else{
        while (pnt != NULL && pnt->idf.numCompte != numCpt) {
            pnt=pnt->next;
            if (pnt==first) {        // Remove the first node
                first=pnt->next;
                free(pnt);
            }else if (pnt->next==NULL) {  // Remove the last node 
                pnt->prc->next=NULL;
                free(pnt);
            }else{                       // Remove a moddle node
                pnt->prc->next=pnt->next; // <==== !!!!
                pnt->next->prc=pnt->prc;  // <==== !!!!
                free(pnt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I still have the same problem, even if I tried to do this method:
 -(pnt->prc)->next=pnt->next;

Comment: please better format your code for readability

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask].  What is "a problem?"

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: if you are implementing a linked list yourself, consider using a sentry node. see http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1

Comment: thanks for your support. i found th selution ^^

Answer (score 1):

The line after the while loop causes the problem, i.e. pnt=pnt->next should be after the if-else if . So if there is only 1 node, then pnt will be NULL, which causes problem in the else part. The modified code is :

```
void suppCompte (int numCpt) 
{  
   CompteBancaire *pnt=first;
   if (first==NULL)
       printf("la liste vide !\n");
   else
   {   

      while (pnt!=NULL && pnt->idf.numCompte!=numCpt)
        CompteBancaire *temp=pnt;
         if (pnt==first)           // Remove the first node
        {       first=pnt->next;
        }
         else if (pnt->next==NULL)  // Remove the last node 
        {        pnt->prc->next=NULL;
         }
        else                       // Remove a moddle node
        {        pnt->prc->next=pnt->next;  <==== !!!!
                 pnt->next->prc=pnt->prc;   <==== !!!!
         }
        pnt=temp->next;
        free(temp);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check your pointers to make sure that they are not NULL.  This can be done with two easy if loops.  You always have to watch out for this sort of thing with doubly linked lists, and you have to think carefully about the order of your instructions.

Then, after you set the pointers to sort of "point around" the current node, set the pointers of the current node to NULL.

Also, consider using `gdb`.  It is the Gnu DeBugger.  If you compile with `gcc`, you can say `gcc -g <files and other stuff>` to compile with `gdb` debugging symbols.  Then you can run the program in `gdb`, and inspect the values of variables, watch stuff evaluate, etc.  You can probably find a lot of good material on this.